# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{ln} \mathit{x}}{1-x}dx$

Tags: integration, logarithms

Please help me with this integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{ln} \mathit{x}}{1-x}dx$$

If it is useful, the previous demand is to prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{ln} \mathit{x}}{1-x^a}dx$ is convergent for all $a>0$

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @Nguyễn Quang Anh: What techniques do you know to do integration?

Comment: I am used to definite and improper integral, properties of integral with parameters and Euler integral

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661746/prove-that-int-limits-01-xa1-x-1-ln-x-dx-sum-limits-n-1-infty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral of interest is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx=-\text{Li}_2(1)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

where $\text{Li}_2(x)$ is the dilogarithm function.

---

**ALTERNATIVE DEVELOPMENT:**

Note that we can expand $\log(x)$ as $\log(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x} \,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x} \,dx \tag 1\\\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1n \int_\epsilon^1 (1-x)^{n-1}\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-\epsilon)^n}{n^2} \tag 3\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2} \tag 4\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

where the legitimacy of interchanging the integral and series in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and the legitimacy of interchanging the limit with the series in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$ is provided by uniform convergence.

---

> We could rely on Lebesgue integration and the Dominated Convergence Theorem rather than Riemann integration and Uniform Convergence.  We proceed as follows.

First, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(1-x)^n}{n}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-(xy)^N}{1-xy}\right)\,dy\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Next, inasmuch as $\left|\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-(xy)^N}{1-xy}\right)\,dy \right|\le -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ for $x\in (0,1)$, and $\int_0^1 \left|-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\right|\,dx$ is Lebesgue integrable, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{\pi^2}{6}&=-\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n \int_0^1  (1-x)^{n-1}\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(1-x)^n}{n}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-x)^n}{n}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Thank you very much but can I get a more basic solution that does not include special function.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've edited to add another way forward that doesn't appeal to special functions.

Comment: Exchanging sum and integral isn't as casual a task as is presented here.

Comment: The series cannot converge uniformly on $[0,1]$ since $\log(x)$ has a singularity at $x=0$. The series does converge uniformly on $[r,1]$ for any $r>0$ so
$$\int_r^1\frac{\log(x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_r^1(1-x)^{n-1}{\rm d}x =  -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-r)^n}{n^2}$$
Then taking $r\to 0$ in the end should give the result.

Comment: @winther Yes, that is the way to proceed.  The latter series does converge uniformly and hence one may interchange the limit with the series.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Winther Your comment inspired me to supplement the post by legitimizing the formal interchange of operations by invoking the Dominated Convergence Theorem.   Again, thank you for your comment!  -Mark

Answer (score 3):

By setting $x=e^{-t}$ we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt = -\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{+\infty}te^{-(n+1)t}\,dt=-\zeta(2). $$
In a similar way,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)\,dx }{1-x^{\alpha}}=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2}=-\psi'(\alpha+1)$$
for any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much but can I get a more basic solution that does not include series.

Comment: @NguyễnQuangAnh: there is no simple way to express $\zeta(2)$ without using a series (except $\pi^2/6$, but to prove that equality is quite non-trivial), hence I think there is no "more basic" solution.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it

Comment: @NguyễnQuangAnh $-\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(1\right)$ $\underline{\texttt{is not}}$ a 'more basic solution'.